# Header & Footer Flipping in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, header, footer

Has anybody experienced this behaviour in jQuery mobile?

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="main" class="ui-responsive" >
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="ui-grid-a" >
        <div  class="ui-block-a" style="width:30%">
            <div id="searchdiv">
                <input  type="search" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="Suche..." data-clear-btn="true"/>
                <span id="matches"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"  id="contentblock">
</div>
<!-- page content -->
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div class="ui-grid-a" >
    <div class="ui-block-a">         
        <img style="padding:5px 0 5px 15px" width="100px" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align:right; font-size: 70%; padding-right: 10px;">      
        <span id="version">VXX</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/worgor/m9uro5je/

When you click inside the contant area the footer is flipping up and down - if you scroll down, the header is doing the same!

the content is larger than the screen, sure bute what I want is that the footer and header is, lets say sticky and staying on top and bottom of the screen independent of screensize.

Comment: Set data-tap-toggle="false" on the header and footer: http://api.jquerymobile.com/toolbar/#option-tapToggle

Comment: You are a Star, works exaktly the way i wanted!!!! thx a lot!!!!